# Increase height of a View on swipe up in react native expo

Tags: react-native, gesture

I have a container that contains multiple views like this :

```
export default function MyComponent() {

<View *** container *** >
<View> // some stuff </View>
<View> // some stuff </View>
<ScrollView> // some stuff </ScrollView>
</View
}
```

The ScrollView is about 40% of the container's height, in absolute position.

What I need to do is to be able to extend it over the whole screen with a swipe up.

I tried to use some modals npm package but I can't make it work.

Comment: When you say on swipe up do you mean  that on swipe anywhere on screen or just on scrolls in the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- From my experience, `ScrollView`s and `FlatList`s work best when they have a flex of one and are wrapped in a parent container that limits their size.
- I couldnt determine if you wanted to wrap the entire screen in a `GestureDector` and listen to swipes or if you only wanted the `ScrollView` to listen for scroll events. Because you want the `ScrollView` to take up the entire screen, I assume you wanted to listen to onScroll events

So here's a [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/feLKce2wW) I put together:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { 
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  useWindowDimensions
  } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Box from './components/Box';
import randomColors from './components/colors'
const throttleTime = 200;

// min time between scroll events (in milliseconds)
const scrollEventThrottle = 100;
// min up/down scroll distance to trigger animatino
const scrollYThrottle = 2;

export default function App() {
  const scrollViewAnim = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  let lastY = React.useRef(0).current;
  // used to throttle scroll events
  let lastScrollEvent = React.useRef(Date.now()).current;
  const [{ width, height }, setViewDimensions] = React.useState({});
  const [isScrollingDown, setIsScrollingDown] = React.useState(false);
  const [scrollViewTop, setScrollViewTop] = React.useState(400);
  // scroll view is 40% of view height
  const defaultHeight = height * .4;
  // call onLayout on View before scrollView
  const onLastViewLayout = ({nativeEvent})=>{
    // combine the y position with the layout height to
    // determine where to place scroll view
    setScrollViewTop(nativeEvent.layout.y + nativeEvent.layout.height)
  }
  const onContainerLayout = ({nativeEvent})=>{
    // get width and height of parent container
    // using this instead of useWindowDimensions allow
    // makes the scrollView scale with parentContainer size 
    setViewDimensions({
      width:nativeEvent.layout.width,
      height:nativeEvent.layout.height
    })
  }
  //animation style
  let animatedStyle = [styles.scrollView,{
    height:scrollViewAnim.interpolate({
      inputRange:[0,1],
      outputRange:[defaultHeight,height]
    }),
    width:width,
    top:scrollViewAnim.interpolate({
      inputRange:[0,1],
      outputRange:[scrollViewTop,-10]
    }),
    bottom:60,
    left:0,
    right:0
  }]
  const expandScrollView = ()=>{
    Animated.timing(scrollViewAnim,{
      toValue:1,
      duration:200,
      useNativeDriver:false
    }).start()
  }
  const shrinkScrollView = ()=>{
    Animated.timing(scrollViewAnim,{
      toValue:0,
      duration:200,
      useNativeDriver:false
    }).start()
  }
  const onScroll=(e)=>{
    // throttling by time between scroll activations
    if(Date.now() - lastScrollEvent <scrollEventThrottle ){
      console.log('throttling!')
      return
    }
    lastScrollEvent = Date.now()
    // destructure event object
    const {nativeEvent:{contentOffset:{x,y}}} = e;
    const isAtTop = y <= 0
    const isPullingTop = lastY <= 0 && y <= 0
    let yDiff = y - lastY
    let hasMajorDiff = Math.abs(yDiff) > scrollYThrottle
    // throttle if isnt pulling top and scroll dist is small
    if(!hasMajorDiff && !isPullingTop  ){
      return
    }
    const hasScrolledDown = yDiff > 0
    const hasScrolledUp = yDiff < 0
    if(hasScrolledDown){
      setIsScrollingDown(true);
      expandScrollView()
    }
    if(isAtTop || isPullingTop){
      setIsScrollingDown(false)
      shrinkScrollView();
    }
    lastY = y
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onContainerLayout}>
      <Box color={randomColors[0]} text="Some text"/>
      <Box color={ randomColors[1]} text="Some  other text "/>
      <View style={styles.lastView} 
        onLayout={onLastViewLayout}>
        <Text>ScrollView Below </Text>
      </View>
      <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
        <ScrollView
          onScroll={onScroll}
          style={{flex:1}}
        >
          {randomColors.map((color,i)=>
            <Box color={color} height={60} text={"Item Number "+(i+1)}/>
          )}
        </ScrollView>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    padding: 8,
  },
  scrollView:{
    // position:'absolute',
    position:'absolute',
    marginVertical:10,
    height:'40%',
    backgroundColor:'lightgray'
  },
  lastView:{
    alignItems:'center',
    paddingVertical:5,
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderTopWidth:1
  }
});
```

The result is that on downward scrolling, the scrollview expands and takes up the entire screen, and shrinks when the user scrolls to the top.

Edit : I found that simply grabbing the y position and the height of the view directly before the scroll view made it easy to calculate where the position the ScrollView, allowing for the ScrollView to be positioned absolute all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example of how to use FlatList (similar to ScrollView) and allow for the scrolling behavior you are wanting:

```js
import React from "react";
import {Text,View} from "react-native";

const App = () => {

  const myData = {//everything you want rendered in flatlist}

  const renderSomeStuff = () => {
      return (
         <View>
           <Text> Some Stuff </Text>
         </View>
    )
  };

  const renderOtherStuff = () => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text> Other Stuff </Text>
        </View>
      );
  };


  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={myData}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator
        ListHeaderComponent={
          <View>
            {renderSomeStuff()}
            {renderOtherStuff()}
          </View>
        }
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
        )}
        ListFooterComponent={
          <View></View>
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```